# If date between two dates in second table return value

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I am trying to determine if a datetime is between a beginning datetime and ending datetime and if it is return a value(s) that match this. It is working in data.table but want to get it working in DPLYR.

So if you have datetimes:

```
2017-07-01 02:15:00 
2017-07-01 02:30:00
```

look these up in a second table

```
begin,      end,                           value1,  value2
2017-07-01 00:01:00,  2017-07-01 01:00:00,  1,       2
2017-07-01 01:01:00,  2017-07-01 02:00:00,  3,       4
2017-07-01 02:01:00,  2017-07-01 03:00:00,  5,       6
```

return

```
date                value1   value2
2017-07-01 02:15:00    5        6     
2017-07-01 02:30:00    5        6
```

There are many of the lookup values so it would be a few hundred lookup date times.

I have this working with data.table but want to use DPLYR to reduce dependence on many packages.  This is what I have so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

dates <- read_csv("date1.csv") %>% 
  mutate(date = as_datetime(date))

lookup <- read_csv("lookup.csv") %>% 
  mutate(begin = as_datetime(begin),
         end = as_datetime(end))

dates <- data.table(dates)
lookup <- data.table(lookup)
setkey(lookup, begin, end)
dates[, c("begin", "end") := date]  
test.df <- foverlaps(dates, lookup)[, c("date", "value1", "value2"), 
                                        with = FALSE]
```

I was thinking of using something like:

```
test <- dates %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(value1 = ifelse( lookup$begin >= date & date <= lookup$end, lookup$value1, ""))
```

Here is the dates to look up:

```
    dates <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1498867200, 1498868100, 1498869000, 
1498869900, 1498870800, 1498871700, 1498872600, 1498873500, 1498874400, 
1498875300, 1498876200, 1498877100, 1498878000, 1498878900, 1498879800, 
1498880700, 1498881600, 1498882500), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = "date", class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

The lookup table:

```
    lookup <- structure(list(begin = structure(c(1498867260, 1498870860, 1498874460, 
1498878060, 1498881660, 1498885260, 1498888860, 1498892460, 1498896060
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), end = structure(c(1498870800, 
1498874400, 1498878000, 1498881600, 1498885200, 1498888800, 1498892400, 
1498896000, 1498899600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    value1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L), value2 = c(2L, 
    4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L)), .Names = c("begin", 
"end", "value1", "value2"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Use non-equi joins in `data.table` instead of `foverlaps`, and doing operations `rowwise` is not a substitute for it.

Comment: Hi, thanks and that is an option two but I would like to use DPLYR for this. The one option I thought of was to switch the dataframe to long format, join it to a datetime sequence that is every 15 minutes (since all data is in quarter hour) then do a fill down for the values and then do another join. This is possible but it seems convoluted even for my amateur coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dates <- dates %>% 
  mutate(match_date = format(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
         match_hour = hour(date - minutes(1)))

lookup <- lookup %>% 
  mutate(match_date = format(begin, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
         match_hour = hour(begin))


left_join(dates, lookup, by = c("match_date", "match_hour")) %>% 
  filter(date >= begin & date <= end) %>% 
  select(- match_date, - match_hour) %>% 
  head()

# A tibble: 6 x 5
#                  date               begin                 end value1 value2
#                <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>  <int>  <int>
# 1 2017-07-01 00:15:00 2017-07-01 00:01:00 2017-07-01 01:00:00      1      2
# 2 2017-07-01 00:30:00 2017-07-01 00:01:00 2017-07-01 01:00:00      1      2
# 3 2017-07-01 00:45:00 2017-07-01 00:01:00 2017-07-01 01:00:00      1      2
# 4 2017-07-01 01:00:00 2017-07-01 00:01:00 2017-07-01 01:00:00      1      2
# 5 2017-07-01 01:15:00 2017-07-01 01:01:00 2017-07-01 02:00:00      3      4
# 6 2017-07-01 01:30:00 2017-07-01 01:01:00 2017-07-01 02:00:00      3      4
```

First I extract the dates and hour of the day to match on. I substract one minute from the date in the `dates`-table as your end times in your `lookup`-table contain the times sharp (I mean e.g. 01:00:00). As I want to join on the begin-dates to get the right matching hour (e.g. 0 in this case), I substract the minute.

Then I do a `left_join` of `dates` and `lookup` and `filter` on your desired criteria.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Because in the real dataset the data in lookup spans more than an hour or even day in some cases but when I change the code by removing hour it works and I think it will work when it spans for more than a day or two so thank you. Seems like there would be other ways to accomplish this as well.

Comment: It does seem that there are some data that it does not fill in if the range of dates spans more than a few days so it works sort of.

Comment: just a note - because of issues with multi days covered, I ended up just joining the lookup file with values to a datetime 15 minute sequence and used the tidyr fill down to fill the NA values (note prior NA values were converted to 9999 before filling and then back to NA after the fill). This was then just joined with the dates file I was looking up.